# Modification on GUI in C++ SkeletalViewer

Tags: c++, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am new in Kinect programming and I am trying to practise on them. As I know, WPF application is quite a good alternative to work on application that need to work on GUI. I am currently practising the coding on SkeletalViewer application, but it seems like harder to see where the GUI is defined in C++ program? Can anyone give me an idea on how C++ define the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a project using WPF but if you need this to be done in C++ then I guess you could transfer live joints' x,y,z data into your C++ application. Once you done that its easy to recreate the joints on C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ projects on the Kinect SDK samples use Windows API to define the GUI: everything is done programmatically. Find on the files the function CreateWindow (or CreateWindowEx): that's where the GUI is defined. There is no graphical editor for them, you won't find anything like that. If you need a graphical editor, you should try the C#/WPF samples on the SDK.